# How to print hex to the screen in python

Tags: python

I am trying to get python to print a hex string to the screen and not convert it to the ascii character.

```
>>> x=b'\x5e\x2e\x6d'
>>> x
'^.m'
```

Is there a way to print this to the screen as `'\x5e\x2e\x6d'` instead of `'^.m'`

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`b'\x5e\x2e\x6d'` and `b'^.m'` are identical as far as Python is concerned. However, you can format it as you desire like this:

```
>>> x = b'\x5e\x2e\x6d'
>>> print(''.join(map(r'\x{:x}'.format, bytearray(x))))
\x5e\x2e\x6d
```

or in Python3

```
>>> print(''.join([r'\x{:x}'.format(c) for c in x]))
\x5e\x2e\x6d
```

or in Python2

```
>>> print(''.join([r'\x{:x}'.format(ord(c)) for c in x]))
\x5e\x2e\x6d
```

Comment: I was cooking up a `bytearray` answer ... :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to encode the string to hex.

```
>>> x=b'\x5e\x2e\x6d'
>>> x
'^.m'
>>> x.encode("hex")
'5e2e6d'
```

Comment: I think he also wanted the `\x`'s.

Comment: Unless you wish to make the string itself a series of hex values then thesquaregroot's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20407313/3071418) is the appropriate choice.

Answer (score 1):

You want to escape the slash with another slash:

```
'\\x5e'
```

Answer (score 0):

For extra points add `02` before the `x` to print single digit hex numbers as eg \x0f as you probably expect.

```
>>> print(''.join([r'\x{:02x}'.format(c) for c in x]))
```